# Getting Error when using getContext in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, canvas

I am trying to create the matrix rain effect as my background in react. I have created a matrix rain rain function that I use to wrap all of my other components with. But I get an error saying 'TypeError: canvas.getContext is not a function'. I am trying to follow the template mentioned on this site https://medium.com/@pdx.lucasm/canvas-with-react-js-32e133c05258 What am I doing wrong here? why is it not working?

MatrixRain.js file

```
import './MatrixRain.css';
import React, {useEffect, useContext, useRef, useState, useCallback} from 'react';    

const MatrixRain = ( props ) => {
    const canvasRef = useRef(null)
  
    useEffect(() => {
      const canvas = canvasRef.current;
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d'); //this line is giving me an error

    }, [])

    return (
        <div className='matrix-rain' ref={canvasRef}>
            {props.children}
        </div>
    )
};

export default MatrixRain
```

App.js file

```
import React, { useState, useReducer, createContext, useContext } from 'react';
import PostList from './components/PostList/PostList.js';
import Title from './containers/Title/Title.js';
import Pagination from './components/Pagination/Pagination.js';
import Navbar from './containers/Navbar/Navbar.js';
import Button from './components/Button/Button.js';
import Store from './store/Store.js';
import MatrixRain from './containers/MatrixRain/MatrixRain'
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Routes,
  Route,
  Link,
  Outlet,
  useParams
} from 'react-router-dom';


const App = () => {

    return (
        <div>
          <Store>
            <MatrixRain>
              <Button />
              <Title />
              <Navbar />
              <PostList />
              <Pagination />
            </MatrixRain>
          </Store>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I found out what the problem was, all I had to do was change

```
    <div className='matrix-rain' ref={canvasRef}>
        {props.children}
    </div>
```

to

```
    <canvas className='matrix-rain' ref={canvasRef}>
        {props.children}
    </canvas>
```

and that did the trick for me